# How to create this view with constraints programtically

Tags: swift, xcode, view, uiview, constraints

I feel this is pretty simple to accomplish but I can't seem to figure it out. I'm fairly new to not using the storyboard and trying to learn how to set my constraints programatically for my views. I created the view that I want easily in storyboard but can't seem to get it programatically.

I have my view controller has my parent view, and then I call a container view. I imagine in the container view is where I setup my constraints but I can't get the height of my view to stay the same every-time I change to a different device

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    var clariView = ClariContainerView()
    view.addSubview(clariView)
}
```

}

This my view controller and then my ClariContainerView looks like this:

```
class ClariContainerView: UIView {

lazy var clariQuestionView: UIView = {
    let containerView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 0))
    containerView.backgroundColor = .blue
    containerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return containerView
}()

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    setupView()
}


required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: coder)
    setupView()
}

public func setupView() {
    addSubview(clariQuestionView)
    setupLayout()
}

public func setupLayout() {
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        clariQuestionView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 169)
    ])
}
```

}

What I'm trying to recreate is this:
[image]

I need the height of the blue view to always be 169.

Comment: I'd suggest you use the Interface Builder and Autolayout - they are much easier to use and it's harder for information to get lost in code.

Comment: I wish I could, but it's my work that's trying to stay away from using storyboard and xibs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you would do that:

- First, you don't need to define a frame for your containerView since the `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false`statement is specifying that you'll be using auto-layout and therefore the frame will be ignored:

```
    lazy var clariQuestionView: UIView = {
        let containerView = UIView()
        containerView.backgroundColor = .blue
        containerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return containerView
    }()
```

- And here is how you would define your constraints. You need to set height, but also need to pin the view to the bottom, the leading, and the trailing edges of self.view:

```
    public func setupLayout() {
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            clariQuestionView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 169),
            clariQuestionView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor),
            clariQuestionView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor),
            clariQuestionView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor)
        ])
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For such a basic layout you don't really need to add `heightAnchor`. Here is a simple way to achieve desired behavior + bonus — a code snippet to adjust height according to the device's `safeAreaInsets`.

```
class ClariContainerView: UIView {
    lazy var clariQuestionView: UIView = {
        let desiredContainerHeigh = 169
        // If you want, you can use commented code to adjust height according to the device's safe area.
        // This might be needed if you want to keep the same height over safe area on all devices.
        // let safeAreaAdjustment = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController?.view.safeAreaInsets.bottom ?? 0
        let containerView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: UIScreen.main.bounds.height - 169, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 169))
        containerView.backgroundColor = .blue
        containerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
        return containerView
    }()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupView()
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        setupView()
    }

    public func setupView() {
        addSubview(clariQuestionView)
    }
}
```